# Yii CGridView column names from two tables using ids

Tags: view, yii, grid, yii1.x

### index.php

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'header' => 'User Name',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->sud_profile->user_id)',//This will use the relationship and get all the details of the paticular user from users table
        ),
        'subject',
        'message',
```

I have two tables i want to display names instead of ids.
My two tables are:

table 1

```
msg table
---------
id sender receiver subject message
------------------------------------
1   3      4         wish   have a god
```

table 2

```
--------
sud_profile
-------------
id user_id firstname lastname
1    2     kumar         rai
```

From these two tables i want to display names based on ids like sender and user_id.

Comment: add both of your models or share the relations that you have declared inside the models and the `sender` and `receiver` inside the `msg` table are holding id from the `user` table? and you want to display `name` ? or `username` for these columns as the `sud_profile` table already holding the user `first` and `last` names ?

Comment: hey, do mark the answer as correct if it helped you out

Answer (score 0):

You should have added the code for the respective models or add the respective relations in both of the models but i will attempt to guide you so that you could follow up according to your code.

You can call the relation defined inside the `Message` model to access the user and then display the `username`.

### About `msg` table

i assume that the `sender` and `receiver` columns are holding the `id` from the `user` table, you should have the relations defined inside the `Message` model or define one now and add the below inside your relations array (*change your model names and field names if different*).

As you have the `sender` and `receiver` 2 columns both holding different `user_id` so you need to define 2 relations.

```
 public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
          '_sender' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'sender'),
          '_receiver' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'receiver'),
        );
    }
```

and then inside the `GridView` change your column configurations to the following.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
    array(
        'name'=>'sender',
        'header'=>'Sender',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('data-title'=>'Sender'),
        'value'=>'$data->_sender->username'
    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'receiver',
        'header'=>'Receiver',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('data-title'=>'Receiver'),
        'value'=>'$data->_receiver->username'
    ),

))
);
```

### About `sud_profile` table

You need to do the same for the `sud_profile` table, define the relation and display it using the relation inside the gridview.

Your relation will look like below

```
 public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
          '_user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        );
    }
```

And use the relation like below inside your gridview column configurations

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
         array(
            'name'=>'user_id',
            'header'=>'Username',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('data-title'=>'Sender'),
            'value'=>'$data->_user->username'
         ),    
    ))
);
```